# Which Avatars of Vishnu hold a sword (Nandaka)

Tags: vishnu, krishna, avatars

> Vishnu is usually depicted as four-armed with the four attributes in his hands: the shankha (conch), the Sudarshana Chakra, the padma (lotus) and the Kaumodaki gada (mace)

But Vishnu also has a sword (Nandaka), which incarnations of Vishnu is seen holding the Nandaka? Did Krishna hold the Nandaka?